# Verlinde Formula in geometric quantization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I think I have a fair grasp on the $\rm{SU}(2)$ Verlinde Formula from the algebraic geometry perspective.  I'm hoping to understand better how exactly this relates to the geometric quantization of a symplectic manifold.

In algebraic geometry, we consider $N_{g} = N_{g}(2,L)$ to be the moduli space of rank-2 vector bundles over a curve.  One can show that $c_{1} : \rm{Pic}(N_{g}) \to H^{2}(N_{g}, \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism, so there exists a positive generator of the Picard group $\mathcal{L}$, and the famous $\rm{SU}(2)$ Verlinde formula computes the integer $h^{0}(N_{g}, \mathcal{L}^{k})$, using Riemann-Roch, Kodaira Vanishing, etc.

However, in geometric quantization, we take a symplectic manifold $X$, a pre-quantum line bundle $\mathcal{L}'$ on $X$ whose curvature precisely coincides with the underlying symplectic structure $[\omega] \in H^{2}(X, \mathbb{Z})$.  We can then hope to compute dimension of Hilbert space, algebra of operators, etc, after quantization.

It turns out that $N_{g}$ is a symplectic manifold.  So if we fix its symplectic structure, can we consider that special generating line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ to be a pre-quantum line bundle?  If so, can we choose somehow the curvature to coincide with the symplectic structure?  As far as the Verlinde formula in this other context, am I correct to say it *exactly* computes the dimension of the Hilbert space (assuming compact)?  I guess you often hear the dimension of the Hilbert space is *approximately* the volume of the symplectic space.  But I guess Verlinde computes the dimension of Hilbert space exactly, and some limit of the formula gives the volume of phase space?

Thanks in advance!